# Rocket App hangs on linux while waiting for futex

Tags: linux, rust, rust-rocket, futex

I have a simple rocket 0.5.0-dev app

**main.rs**

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

use rocket::http::{Status};
use rocket::State;
use std::sync::{Mutex, Arc};

struct Event {}

#[get("/health")]
fn health() -> Result<&'static str, Status> {
    Ok("UP")
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> rocket::Rocket {
    rocket::ignite()
        .manage(Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::<Event>::new())))
        .mount("/", routes![health])
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "minimal-example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Author <author@example.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rocket = { git = "https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket" }
rocket_contrib = { git = "https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket" }
chrono = { version = "0.4.19", features = ["serde"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.117", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.59"
rand = "0.7.3"
```

On my development machine (rustc 1.47.0 (18bf6b4f0 2020-10-07) in cygwin) I can compile an run this program no problem with the x86_64-pc-windows-gnu target.

My CI builds this program for x86_64-unknown-linux-musl and packs it into a container.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM docker-registry.default.svc:5000/build/rhel:8
USER 0
COPY . /build
RUN microdnf -y install gcc \
    && curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | bash -s -- -y \
    && source $HOME/.cargo/env \
    && rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl \
    && cd /build \
    && cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
RUN ls -lh /build/target/release

FROM scratch
USER 0
EXPOSE 8080
ENV ROCKET_PORT 8080
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /build/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/myapp .
RUN ls -lh /app
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/myapp"]
```

But as soon as I deploy this image to OSCP I get … nothing. The program just hangs indefinitely. I copied the application out of the container and tried to run it on a linux server (SMP Debian 4.9.30-2 (2017-06-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux) with the same result. I ran strace on it which gave me

```
epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 6, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLPRI|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLET, {u32=0, u64=0}}) = 0
brk(0x564de1356000)                     = 0x564de1356000
socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0, [7, 8]) = 0
brk(0x564de1357000)                     = 0x564de1357000
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x564de08a8b10, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO|SA_NOCLDSTOP, sa_restorer=0x564de08f5716}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
fcntl(7, F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC, 0)            = 9
fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 9, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLPRI|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLET, {u32=1, u64=1}}) = 0
getsockname(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [128->16]) = 0
futex(0x7ffe331e9284, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL
```

It seems the app deadlocks while waiting for a futex, I just have no idea why (and why it doesn't happen on Windows). I already tried compiling with x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu and switching to the system allocator, both to no avail.

Comment: I just run it in my Linux and it works fine. If I run with strace it shows the same as yours. But it looks like it is waiting for a client to connect. Does your CI setup have a client to test your server? Because a web server by its own does nothing...

Comment: It is an Openshift Cluster which regularly polls the /health endpoint.

Comment: Well, in that case I'd dare say that this polling is not reaching the server. Maybe because your rocket is listening at port 8000, but you seem to be exposing port 8080?

Comment: I see your `ENV ROCKET_PORT 8080` and it should work, but in your `strace` it says `sin_port=htons(8000)`

Comment: Good catch. Maybe rocket 0.5 doesn't react to these env variables anymore and it just always bound to the wrong port?

Comment: It does for me... but using the github master is risky. Or maybe your docker is not passing the variable properly, or there is something else messing with your configuration...